# Por que a propriedade "text-align: center" funciona em imagem?

Tags: html, css

Não entendo o porque de `text-align: center` está centralizando a imagem, pois está propriedade não é utilizada para centralizar texto? porque ela centraliza a imagem também? criei um exemplo.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

header#main-header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<header id="main-header">
    <i class="fab fa-500px"></i>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/169e513592.js"></script>
    <h1>File Manager</h1>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O seu "<i>" seria a imagem no caso? Pois no caso ai, é só uma fonte de ícones então vai centralizar como fonte.

Comment: Sam, opa vou sim é que sempre esqueço ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A imagem por incrível que parece eh um elemento inline, assim como a label, span, input, entre outros, então na image incide propriedades como text-align e verticla-align por exemplo. O model-box tem algumas particularidades em comparação com outros elementos inline, mas basicamente eh isso, ela alinha com text-align Pq eh considerada um elemento textual

Comment: vlw, man nem tinha pensado nisso

Comment: @LeandroNascimento a tag img eh um elemento peculiar, repare que como um input ela não tem tag de fechamento, mas diferente da label que tbm eh inline e tem tag de fechamento, pois a Pavel tem conteúdo dentro e a imagem o "conteúdo" vem de um recurso externo "src" que eh o link do arquivo externo. Valeu a força

Answer (score 13):

### Funciona porque uma imagem é um elemento inline

A propridade `text-align` funciona para elementos que sejam inline, uma imagem é um elemento inline, por isso `text-align` funciona em imagens. É como se esses elementos inlines tivessem o comportamento de um texto, mesmo sem necessariamente serem um texto.

#### Uma observação

Esse tipo de coisa funcionar é algo contraintuitivo para quem está iniciando. Lembrando que você pode modificar esse comportamento definindo a propriedade/valor `display:block` para um elemento que é inline.

Answer (score 4):

Uma tarefa comum em CSS é a centralização de textos e imagens.

**1) Centrar linhas de textos:**

Centrar textos de títulos ou parágrafos é a mais simples e comum tarefa de centralização. Basta usar a propriedade CSS 'text-align', conforme mostrado a seguir:

```
P { text-align: center }
H2 { text-align: center }
```

As regras CSS mostradas renderizam cada uma das linhas de P ou de H2 centralizadas na horizontal.

**2) Centrar um bloco de texto ou uma imagem:**

Outra tarefa de centralização consiste em centrar não um texto, mas um bloco como um todo. Dito de outra forma: definir margens esquerda e direirta iguais par um bloco. Para obter esse efeito usamos o valor 'auto' para a proriedade margin. É necessário que o bloco tenha uma largura fixa, pois em se tratando de blocos flexíveis ele assumira a largura total disponível. Observe o exemplo a seguir:

```
P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 6em
}
...
<P class="blocktext">Esse bloco de texto...
```

Esta é, também, a técnica usada para centralizar uma imagem: defina nível de bloco para a imagem e o valor 'auto' para as margens esquerda e direita, conforme mostrado a seguir:

```
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
...
<IMG class="displayed" src="..." alt="...">
```

Num resumo, apesar de sugestivo, `text-align` alinha objetos e não só textos.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Opa obrigado amigo a resposta ajudo muito.